# Can threading damage CPU?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am new to programming and came across a Python3 tutorial on threading. It seems very useful to improve speed and efficiency. My concern would be any damage to processor if I use too many, is this what would be meant by 'over-clocking'?
Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Have you done any research into this at all? Any in the slightest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overclocking is when you make the CPU execute faster than the manufacturer certifies the part for. Using multiple threads is not the same, it's effectively just multitasking and will not cause damage to the processor.

Answer (score 1):

Threading is just running several threads similar to running several different programs concurrently which makes your application perform better. So, it has nothing to do with the processor.

On the other hand **overclocking** means setting your CPU and memory to run at speeds higher than their official speed grade which will eventually damage your processor.

Comment: Actually it probably won't damage the processor. Even if it does not slow itself down when it finds it is too hot, the eventual result of overheating is that the internal logic gates become slower until they cannot perform their designed function and the processor crashes (after which it's doing very little and will cool down). The bad thing about overclocking is that your computer may generate wrong results without any obvious error. Which do you want, garbage generated faster, or the right results every time?

Answer (score 1):

As ServerMonkey said, Overclocking is when you make the CPU execute faster than the manufacturer certifies the part for. This can be done by tweaking the bios settings and this can definitely cause damage to the processor, as it might overheat.

Using multiple threads is asking your machine to run multiple parts of your program in parallel. If you have a CPU with multiple cores (most recent CPUs have at least 2), each core can run a thread in parallel, leading to massive performance increase.

If you create more threads than cores, the operating system will run them apparently in parallel, in fact it will run them one after each other, switching from one to another every 10 milliseconds or so. That still works pretty well.

If you create way to many threads (I am talking of thousands of threads) the overall performance will drop because your operating system will spend a lot of time to manage them.

In any case, you won't make any damage to the CPU by creating threads.